# Validating by user_id in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code that validates by user_id. If the category_name exists, this prevents the creation of a new Object. The code works but I don't believe this is best practice.

```rb
   def create
   @item_category = ItemCategory.new(item_category_params)
   @item_category.user_id = current_user.id
   search = ItemCategory.where(:name => @item_category.name,:user_id => current_user.user_id)

if search.blank?
  respond_to do |format|
    if @item_category.save
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Se ha creado la categoria' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @item_category }    
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @item_category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
else
    respond_to do |duplicate|
    duplicate.html { redirect_to @item_category, alert: 'Categoria Repetida' }
    duplicate.json { render json: @item_category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
  end
end
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to put the validation in your ItemCategory model...

```
class ItemCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :user_id

  ...
end
```

Comment: Excellent! , this what im looking for. 
 can i set an specific message in model ?. 
actually this return this: 
`1 error prohibited this form from being saved:
Name has already been taken`

Thanks!

Comment: You can speciy any message you want... `validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :user_id, :message => 'this is my custom message'`